# Altering SQLite cursors?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an SQLite table Task, and I would like to display the 5 tasks with the highest "priority" in a ListView.

Priority is a complex calculation, so I can't just compute it in SQL and order/limit the result.

To achieve that goal, I was thinking about getting a Cursor with all the tasks, going through the rows to compute and set a "priority" number, and delete/reorder the rows of the cursor so that it shows only the first 5.

From what I found, I can set a "priority" value to a row by extending Cursor so that it exposes CursorWindow.

Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to alter the rows of the Cursor to delete/order them.

Is there a way to do that? If not, I'm also open to other efficient design alternatives.

Of course, I could add a "priority" column in my table, update it every time, and then do the selection with order/limit, but that's not very efficient.

I guess I could also do filtering/ordering in the adapter, but I don't think that's the kind of job an adapter is supposed to do.

Comment: use a `android.database.CursorWrapper` and override `moveToPosition` and `getCount` methods

Comment: How exactly is the priority computed?

Comment: Couldn't you make a SQL `View`, where you will find the calculated priorities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android, there is no easy to install user-defined functions, so if computing the priority is not possible in SQL, you have to do the sorting/filtering manually.

Cursors you get from the database (class [SQLiteCursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursor.html)) are read only, so you cannot store the priority in the cursor itself.

You have to add a level of indirection: create your own class that stores the priority and a reference to the original cursor's row:

```java
class TaskPriority {
    public int priority;
    public int positionInCursor;
};
```

Compute these fields for all rows in the cursor, then sort these objects by priority. Then you can use the first five `positionInCursor` fields to get the actual data.

(If you need some `Cursor` to show the data in a list view, just copy the five rows into a [MatrixCursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MatrixCursor.html).)

Comment: no need for a data duplication using a `MatrixCursor`: all you mentioned in your answer can be done in a `CursorWrapper` (i know that 5 rows is not big deal, but still...)

Comment: @pskink Then write an answer to show how it's done.

Comment: its done the same way you propose in your answer: the only difference is `Cursor`'s data access

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I also need to have a priority column in the resulting cursor. If the "exposing CursorWindow" trick doesn't allow me to change values in the rows, I guess my only choice is to use a MatrixCursor. Otherwise, CursorWrapper is probably better.